# Customising the Help Centre's "What topics can I ask about here?"

Tags: discussion

In the [help centre, in the section **What topics can I ask about here?**](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there's a bunch of text that the moderators can edit.

Is that text ok as it stands? What should be added to it?

Note that there is a separate page for off-topic questions, so text for this page should concentrate on what is **on-topic**.

Answer (score 2):

A first draft.

> Sustainable Living Stack Exchange is for folks dedicated to a lifestyle that can be maintained indefinitely without depleting available resources.
>
> We encourage all sorts of questions about sustainable living, in particular specific problems you come across. When you ask a question, make sure that it is actually **answerable** and please check that it hasn't been asked already, else the question may be [*closed*](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), or marked as a *duplicate*.
>
> If your question is not specifically about sustainable living, it may be on-topic for [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites). If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, where new Stack Exchange communities are created.
>
> For more help, see "What types of questions should I avoid asking?"

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note: many sites use the "What topics can I ask about here?" page to enumerate *both* things that are explicitly on-topic for the site *and* subjects that may **appear** to an outside user to be on-topic but which the community has decided are out of scope. You can do them both in a list format for easy reading. Take [Super User's](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a shopping or product recommendation
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

You don't have to do it this way, but it's a great way to disambiguate any quirks related to this particular community. (For example, if gardening questions are off-topic here, even if you are gardening as a way to have a more sustainable lifestyle, that would be a great thing to put on this page). The ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page provides guidance on style of question (no shopping recommendations, guidelines for good v. bad subjective questions, etc.) than it does subject matter. That page is the same for every Stack Exchange site.